# Is there a zapier-like nodejs package or framework to manage multiple rest integrations in a consistent way?

Tags: node.js, rest, npm, architecture

I'm looking to build integrations to various external API services such as jira, service now, aws, Azure, etc.

I want abstract different rest services with so I can run a function like createdID = create_ticket(title,body,system) and it sends the data to the system in its format.

Each of these integrations typically have an almost ETL like flow:

1. Input data (ex: title, body) ->
2. tranform to external format (ex: in jira summary, description, in service now name , short description
3. Send to associated rest Endpoint with aith
4. Get return value like created ticket
5. Have webhook for future call
6. Take webhook data and transform to internal data schema
7. Save data

I can write this functionality but I'm wondering if there is an existing solution. I would consider an external SaaS platform but prefer module to add to my code. I don't need low code editor, just simple structure. I'm thinking of something similar to logstash but not for continuous stream and to support accepting return values.

I've looked at make (saas platform), apache airflow but none seemed to hit the mark. I looked at node-red but not in depth. Most of these focused on low/no code experience. I was hoping more for a hook oriented system where I can register the transforms as json, and the business logic as functions.

Thanks for any ideas!